# .gradle\caches\6.7.1\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

C:\Users\monika.gradle\caches\6.7.1\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not update C:\Users\monika.gradle\caches\6.7.1\file-changes\last-build.bin

> C:\Users\monika.gradle\caches\6.7.1\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s

Android Studio Details:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use different gradle version

Comment: yes, I tried. but nothing works. I tried a number of solutions available online. Still no success.

Comment: @Monika Sometimes I have a problem like this. If you are in a country that has sanctions from the U.S, It is better to use ProtonVpn. I used it and the problem was solved.